# Safari View Controller with Tab Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller, sfsafariviewcontroller

I want to add a tab to my tab based swift application that open a safari view controller and unwinds to the previous tab when "Done" is tapped. After many attempts to search this on google I have not found a solution. Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to display a SFSafariViewController inside of a UITabBarController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084311/is-it-possible-to-display-a-sfsafariviewcontroller-inside-of-a-uitabbarcontrolle)