# Is it possible to display a SFSafariViewController inside of a UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, sfsafariviewcontroller

I want to load `SFSafariViewController` inside of a tab, so the tab bar is at the bottom of the entire Safari view.

Is this possible? I tried this with no luck:

```
[self.tabBarController presentViewController:sfController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Is it *required* that the Safari view be full screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JAL's answer as a base, I was able to implement this myself in an app that had existing structure with tabs already.

I wanted tab #3 to go into a Safari controller within the tab after a button was pressed on the existing view, and not pop the Safari controller into its own window like it does using Apple's default code.

The key was to swap in a `SFSafariViewController` into the existing `UITabBarController`'s array of view controllers. I saved the existing original view controller on tab #3 (index 2) to come back to it when the Done button was pressed on the Safari controller.

Here's what I did to go into the Safari controller from with my tab when a button was pressed:

```
NSMutableArray *viewArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
self.savedController = [viewArray objectAtIndex:2];
[viewArray replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:safariController];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = viewArray;
[self setTabIconTitle];
```

Then I could swap back to the original view on that tab like this when the Done button was pressed on the Safari controller using this delegate call:

```
- (void)safariViewControllerDidFinish:(SFSafariViewController *)controller
{
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    NSMutableArray *viewArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tabBarController.viewControllers];
    [viewArray replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:self.savedController];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = viewArray;
    [self setTabIconTitle];
}
```

When I swapped controllers in an out of the `tabBarController` view controller array, I lost my tab icon and tab name, so I had to set those. Here is how I fixed that issue (and kept my theming when the tab icon was touched):

```
- (void)setTabIconTitle
{
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *marketplaceTab = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
    marketplaceTab.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab2-icon"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    marketplaceTab.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab2-icon"];
    marketplaceTab.title = @"My Tab";
}
```

I must admit that I am not sure that Apple intended that the `SFSafariViewController` be used in this way within a tab, based on what the normal behavior of calling `SFSafariViewController` currently does. Just be aware that future iOS updates may change this behavior and always test your code when new iOS versions go into Beta.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to achieve this programmatically.  They key to not have the `UITabBar` overlay on top of your `UIViewController` is to set `translucent` to `NO`:

In your AppDelegate.m:

```
@import SafariServices;

// ...

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;

    SFSafariViewController *firstVC = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"]];

    firstVC.title = @"SFSafariViewController";

    UIViewController *secondVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    secondVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    secondVC.title = @"Blue VC";

    tabBarController.viewControllers = @[firstVC, secondVC];

    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```